# Can I re-install MacPorts but leave my Python installation, done via MacPorts, alone?

Tags: macos, macports, python

Okay, I admit it, I didn't really think it through when I clicked on the button to upgrade to Sierra. Having done that, I've of course made MacPorts lose its mind. I mostly don't notice because once I install Python and PIP, I don't do much with MacPorts -- except to install things like LaTeX or `wget`.

Can I re-install MacPorts without messing up my Python installation? I have a lot of packages installed -- numpy, scipy, nltk, sklearn, etc. -- that I would just as soon leave alone. Everything is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your list of installed packages with Macports.  Uninstall your existing copy of Macports (Google search will turn up the two step process).  Then upgrade to the new OS.  Simply install the new Macports for your new macOS and finally install the packages from the "list" you kept.

Save your list of installed ports:

> port -qv installed > myports.txt

Restore your ports following a few steps found here:
https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration

Do NOT upgrade your macOS before exporting or first removing your Macports.  Or you may be forced to manually clean things and start over or perform a tedious migration if Macports will work.

When I upgraded to macOS Sierra - my installed version of Macports would no longer run.

Best of luck!

Comment: I did not, of course, do this before upgrading, but after I made my mess, I uninstalled MacPorts and then simply re-installed Python and PIP. When I ran PIP again, it recognized all the already installed modules. So, phew, bullet avoided there.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is unknown.

Macports is only supported and tested if you do a complete reinstall of it when you chnage the versions of macOS used.

You might be get away with rebuilding only a few of the ports but if you have a problem the only support is delete and reinstall as no one has the time to see what happens when you chnage the OS.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. I would give you an upvote, but apparently my stack-fu on this forum is too weak. I'm going to hold off assigning this as "answered" until a bit more time has passed.